# Notebook does not start after reboot

Tags: boot, gnome, 17.10

So I did this: [Change Login screen background](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/10/change-login-screen-background-ubuntu-17-10/)

Also installed some Ubuntu updates, an hour before.

Now I restarted my machine and it is stuck in a boot loop.

[image]

```
Started Hostname Service.ager. Dispatcher Service....ystem changes.pp link was shut down
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall grub by following these steps:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows